# How to inflate dynamic layout on Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to fit two different layouts on my adapter, but I'm not having success, I've tried different ways, I'm still learning the Kotlin language, but I need to create this adapter, can anyone help me?

```
class AuctionAdapter(
    private val context: Context?,
    private val auctionList: List<Auction>,
    private var viewType: Int
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AuctionAdapter.AuctionHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AuctionHolder {

        val itemView: View = if (this.viewType == 1) {
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_auction, parent, false)
        } else {
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_auctions, parent, false)
        }

        return AuctionHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return auctionList.size
    }

    class AuctionHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

Comment: I posted a code, can you ckeck it?. I like to check your code, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few methods, methods you should implement to make the `RecyclerView` aware of the different row types you want to support.

First, let us add a new `ViewHolder` for the other type you want to support.

```kotlin
class AuctionsHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

Second, let us add `getItemViewType` to `AuctionAdapter`

```
class AuctionAdapter ....

    companion object {
        const val SECTION_AUCTION = 0
        const val SECTION_AUCTIONS = 1

        @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
        @IntDef(SECTION_AUCTION,
                SECTION_AUCTIONS)
        annotation class Section
    }

    @Section
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = auctionList[position].type.oridinal
```

Lastly, let us fix `onCreateViewHolder`

```kotlin
class AuctionAdapter(private val context: Context?, private val auctionList: List<Auction>, private var viewType: Int) : 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder = when (viewType) {
                SECTION_AUCTION -> AuctionHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_auction, parent, false))
                SECTION_AUCTIONS -> AuctionsHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_auctions, parent, false))
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported view type $viewType")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to inflate a RecyclerView, you should do the  next

First Library

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

Second Container

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    />
```

Third Adapter

```
public class Name extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder>{
```

Fourth set Adapter

```
RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```